# Control the form errors display while using {{ form.as_ul }} in Django templates.

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-errors

I like the convenient output form method `{{ form.as_ul }}` but is there a way I can still continue to use it but capture all the errors upfront instead of displaying the error just above each field.

I understand that there are ways to loop through each form element and so on as mentioned in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) but I want to continue to utilize the capability of `form.as_ul()` except get control over error display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this problem by using [Reusable Form Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates).

Its simple...

1. Create a reusable template with the following code snippets based on your need.
2. If you want to display all errors right at the top of the form...

   ```
   {% if form %}
       {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
                 {{field.errors}}
            {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}
       {% for field in form %}
            <li>{{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}</li>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   ```
3. If you want to display all errors right after each form field without the default html elements around error use...

   ```
   {% for field in form %}
       {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
       {% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
4. Used the second template and created a [Inclusion Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: It is what I supposed you to do. :-) And you forgot about `help_text` and `non_field_errors`.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, your comment definitely helped to arrive at the above solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to inherit the new form class from `forms.Form` and alter `as_ul` method as you like. Which isn't very good if you are going to use third-party forms like login form and so on (they won't have this method).

I think the best solution is to create your own [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) and render form with it. It will be as short as `as_ul` (`{% render_form form %}`) but very flexible, it will work with all forms and won't mix HTML and Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I still think the customization for rendering form in templates is quite flexible. I usually do this for my webapps. You may work with a bit javascript and css but not a big problem. Moreover, I think we should try to make the app simple.